# Does ZBAR SDK work for any iphone version?

Tags: ios, zbar

Does ZBAR SDK work for any iPhone devices?

I want to know if it works for other versions other than iPhone 3G or iPhone 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works with all version of iPhone.It does not depend which iPhone you are using if you are compiling with compatible architecture.It works with iOS7 also.You can find compiled version running example [here](https://github.com/markdarling/ZBar-SDK-iOS/archive/master.zip)